# Show Custom emoticon in Android Keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard, emoticons

I have been trying for the last 3 days to show a graphical custom emoticon in the default android message view. I have successfully shown my custom emoticons in place of keys. Now the problem is that I am trying to show a drawable in spanable string builder. But the drawable just does not appear on the keyboard. Here is the code so far:

```
     SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(" "); 
                    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a); 
                    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
//                  ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); 
                    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d);
//                  ss.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                    mComposing.append(":");
                    mComposing.setSpan(new ImageSpan(d), 0,1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(mComposing, 1);
```

I have tried different methods to somehow fit the drawable but it just wont show on the default message view of android. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey SoH, Did you find a solution for your issue? I also have same issue when I am going to add image to Android Messaging app. If you have an answer, please post it as Answer of this thread. Thanks..

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the default message view of android?"  What class isn't properly displaying the ImageSpan, and where did the instance come from?

Answer (score 1):

May be this will be helpful:
[Emoticons-Keyboard](https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard)

See this also: [Implementations of Emoji (Emoticon) View/Keyboard Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768930/implementations-of-emoji-emoticon-view-keyboard-layouts)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use:

`String txt = "<img src=\"" + resourceID + "\"/>";` to generate an HTML tag and after that

`Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(txt, emojiGetter, null);`
`editTextObj = setText(spanned,BufferType.SPANNABLE);`

where `emojiGetter` is

```
private ImageGetter emojiGetter = new ImageGetter() {
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source){
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

        Drawable emoji = getResources().getDrawable(id);
        int w = (int)emoji.getIntrinsicWidth() ;
        int h = (int)emoji.getIntrinsicHeight() ;
        emoji.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
        return emoji;
    }
};
```

It works fine for me. I've created a CustomEditText component to simplify this conversion.

Comment: Hey iflorit, I also has the same issue which an image doesn't display in Android messaging app. I created a custom keyboard using SOftKeyboard sample in SDK. I tried your code but it only display a small square with OBJ text, not my image. I noticed that in your code, you have set the image to a EditText. But in Android messaging app, we can't access its EditText. But in custom keyboard I insert letters to Messaging app using SoftKeyboard sample's StringBuilder object. Is there any way to insert images to messaging app using that StringBuilder object? Thanks in Advnce..!!

Comment: No, It is not a solution. You have to get the unicode for all the emojis and print them.

Answer (score 0):

i have achieved it doing like this

```
 ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() 
                {
                    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.e041);
                        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        return d;
                    }
                };

                Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src='" + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.e041) + "'/>", imageGetter, null);

             getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(cs, 1);
```

//but it override the last entered text see [**my question here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604043/embedding-emojiemoticons-images-to-custom-softkeyboard-android)